# websockets difference between ws.on and ws.onmessage

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am using websockets in javascript to connect to an API and read some data.

Here is the code:

```js
function processHUOBIAPI(client,exchange_name,exchange_wss,exchange_symbol)
{
  // Define constants
  const WebSocket = require('ws');
  const pako = require('pako');

  // Open connection once one is established
  var wss = new WebSocket(exchange_wss);

  wss.onopen = () =>
  {
    // Send request to subscribe
    var symbol = exchange_symbol.toLowerCase()
    wss.send(JSON.stringify(
      {
        "sub": "market." + symbol + ".kline.1min",
        "id": symbol
      }
    ));
  };

  // Parse channel information and send to Redis
  wss.onmessage = (data) =>
  {
    //typedef data;
    console.log("Receive message", data);
    let text = pako.inflate(data, {
        to: 'string'
    });
    mssg = JSON.parse(text);
    if (mssg.ping) {
        wss.send(JSON.stringify({
            pong: mssg.ping
        }));
    } else if (mssg.tick) {
        console.log(mssg);
        //handle(msg);
    } else {
        console.log(text);
    }
  }
```

In this case I get an error:

*..../node_modules/pako/lib/inflate.js:384
  if (inflator.err) { throw inflator.msg || msg[inflator.err]; }
                      ^
unknown compression method*

If I change **"wss.onmessage = (data) =>"** to **"wss.on ('message', (data) => {"** and remove the extra ')' the code works perfectly.

What is the difference between wss.on and wss.onmessage ?

Newbie to this one so appreciate any guidance. Apologies in advance if this is a silly one ....

Answer (score 0):

The library [WS](https://github.com/websockets/ws) is a wrapper for the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) so "onmessage" won't work here.